# How to place background image in ZStack without ruining animation?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiscrollview, scrollview

MRE

```
struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ScrollView {
                    ZStack {
                        Image("paperBG")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(geometry.size, contentMode: .fill)
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                        Text("hi")
                            .navigationBarTitle("Title")
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to have a scroll view with a background image edge to edge. Also you can see that the animation will alter the size of the background as the title gets animated to the top.

Answer (score 0):

The `GeometryReader` that you are using to find the window size is delivering different sizes depending on how the navigation title is being displayed. If you could get the size of the window without using a `GeometryReader`, or if you could just use `.scaledToFill` instead, then that would give you a solution. Otherwise, it works better if the `NavigationView` is inside the `GeometryReader`:

```swift
struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {
                    ZStack {
                        Image("paperBG")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(geometry.size, contentMode: .fill)
                            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                        Text("hi")
                            .navigationBarTitle("Title")
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If it's not right yet then perhaps you can provide your "paperBG" for testing with and elaborate a bit more on how you expect it to behave.